# Using sequence to complete arguments to a function

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a function of, say 4 arguments `f[a,b,{c,e},d]` where some of the arguments are lists. Given a list of triplets that are possible last-three-arguments to `f` I'd like to paste them as arguments to `f` as in

`Map[f[2, # /. List -> Sequence] &, {{1, {2, -2}, 3}, {0, {2, -2},  4}, {3, {5, -5}, 7}}]`

but this gives me

`{f[2, 1, 2, -2, 3], f[2, 0, 2, -2, 4], f[2, 3, 5, -5, 7]}`

whereas I wanted

`{f[2, 1, {2, -2}, 3], f[2, 0, {2, -2}, 4], f[2, 3, {5, -5}, 7]}`

How can I get the result I want?

Comment: Apply to the first level is the best solution (in my opinion)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
lst = {{1, {2, -2}, 3}, {0, {2, -2}, 4}, {3, {5, -5}, 7}};

f[2, ##] & @@@ lst
```

> ```
> {f[2, 1, {2, -2}, 3], f[2, 0, {2, -2}, 4], f[2, 3, {5, -5}, 7]}
> ```

Alternatively,

```
Apply[f[2, ##] &, lst, 1]
Map[f[2, ## & @@ #] &, lst]
Map[f[2, Sequence @@ #] &, lst]
FlattenAt[f[2, #], 2] & /@ lst
f @@ Prepend[#, 2] & /@ lst
Prepend[f @@ #, 2] & /@ lst
```

Comment: One more variation for your list: `f[2, Delete[#, 0]] & /@ lst`. However, I still prefer your very first solution.